# How make url for action of current controller in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I want to use some URL helper in blade, which make URL for another action of current controller. For example, my current route is `MuMu@index` and I want make URL for another action `show`.

Comment: `action('MuMu@show')` ?

Comment: It works, but I have complex controller structure. It takes a line only to write an URL for an action. And no need to write the controller name. It is the same. I want only action name ( `thisAction('show')` )

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways is to create helper:

```
function thisAction($action, $params) {
 $route = Route::current()->getAction()['controller'];
 $controller = "\\". explode('@', $route)[0];
 return action($controller . '@' . $action, $params);
}
```

So in blade: `{{ thisAction('show', $myParam) }}`. Also one could extend laravel syntax, so in the result it will be `@thisAction ('show')`, but now I do not know how to do this.